# Add Comment fails -- never posting comment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login

I've been recently sporadically encountering an issue when posting comments. I write the comment, hit the ADD COMMENT button, and occasionally an image of a cat flashes and then a blank page is displayed in the browser, and a URL in the location bar that never finishes loading. When I reload, same thing (though not cat image). If I go back, the comment is gone.

Perhaps related, sometimes when I open new tabs on the SO site, the new tab seems not to know I'm logged in. A reload sometimes corrects that and sometimes not -- I occasionally have to log in again.

This did not used to happen, and the fact that nobody else has posted about it suggests it's something specific to my system. So, here are details:

```
WinXP Pro SP3
Firefox 3.6 (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6)
```

The biggest change on my system recently is that I got rid of AVG antivirus (not the full suite, just the free AV) and started using MS Security Essentials.

If nobody else is encountering this, I'll chalk it up to interference by the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try clearing your browser cache to be safe, but this does sound like client network connectivity issues to me.

I might also recommend trying a different web browser just to see if that improves / worsens things.

Comment: Today it happened again, but before it happened, I kept getting notified that I was logged out. The way I visit SO is to open a folder of saved bookmarks with searches on the topics I'm interested in, and then opening tabs with the specific questions listed in the searches. Today, all of those opened fine, but when I clicked on a link in the first one, it told me I wasn't logged on, as did all further clicks. I logged back in, and began responding to questions, and after a few comments, one of them got lost. I've frequently had problems with OID, actually, not just recently.

Comment: It just happened again, but this time with the cat picture, and "something bad happened" as text next to the image. It seems that if I reload the page before starting my comment, I have fewer lost comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is eaten by the spiral of doom:

[image]

Please note that it is not a spiral, which is why tracking this bug down is so very, very difficult.